# Searching a dictionary in Python 2

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, md5

I have created a dictionary in python, this is some sample code from it.

```
filesAndHashes = dict()
...
>>>print filesAndHashes
{
"/home/rob/Desktop/test.txt":"1c52fe8fbb1463d541c2d971d9890c24",
"/home/rob/Desktop/file.dat":"6386ba70e82f11aa027bfc9874cd58cb",
"/home/rob/Desktop/test2.exe":"5b73c2a88fab97f558a07d40cc1e9d8e"
}
```

So all this is, is a file path and the MD5 of the file.

So what I want to do now is, I have found some MD5's of interest and created a list of them and want to search the dictionary for each MD5 in my list and return the file path to me for each hash.

Also the way the program works, there will never be an MD5 in my list that isn't in the dictionary, so not worried about error checking that.

Please feel free to ask for my information

Thanks.

Comment: Are the hashes guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: Yes @timgeb, as it will only every be scanning a max of about 6 files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a path -> hash mapping, but you need a hash -> path mapping. Assuming the hashes are unique, reverse the dictionary

```
>>> filesAndHashes = {'foo': '123', 'bar': '456'}
>>> hashesAndFiles = {hash:fname for fname,hash in filesAndHashes.iteritems()}
>>> hashesAndFiles
{'123': 'foo', '456': 'bar'}
```

Now just iterate over your list and report matches:

```
>>> hashes = ['456']
>>> for hash in hashes:
...     filename = hashesAndFiles[hash]
...     print(filename)
... 
bar
```

If you cannot rule out that hashes are not unique, which in theory is possible, use a `defaultdict`.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> hashesAndFiles = defaultdict(list)
>>> 
>>> filesAndHashes = {'foo': '123', 'bar': '456', 'baz': '456'}
>>> for fname, hash in filesAndHashes.items():
...     hashesAndFiles[hash].append(fname)
... 
>>> hashesAndFiles
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'123': ['foo'], '456': ['baz', 'bar']})
>>> 
>>> hashes = ['456']
>>> for hash in hashes:
...     for filename in hashesAndFiles[hash]:
...         print(filename)
... 
baz
bar
```

Catch KeyErrors as needed (from your question I assumed you don't expect any non existing hashes in your list).

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the dictionary so that the Keys are the Hashes, since you want to search with the Hashes.

Then simply search for the key in the dictionary with: `filesAndHashes_reversed.get( hash_value, None )`

```
filesAndHashes_reversed = { value: key for key, value in filesAndHashes.iteritems() }
hash_list = [ hash_1,hash_2, hash_3, ]
for hash in hash_list:
    if filesAndHashes_reversed.get( hash, None ) == None:
        print( "Not Found" )
    else:
        print( filesAndHashes_reversed.get( hash, None ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you aren't using the right approach but first I'll answer the question as asked.

To find the FIRST match you can do this:

```
def find_item(md5hash)
  for k,v in a.iteritems():
    if v == md5hash:
       return k
```

Note that this is the first match. In theory it is possible to have multiple entries with the same hash but the OP has said that the hashes are expected to be unique. But in that case why not use them as the key? This makes it easy to search for them:

```
hashes_and_files = dict()

hashes_and_files["1c52fe8fbb1463d541c2d971d9890c24"]="/home/rob/Desktop/test.txt"
hashes_and_files["6386ba70e82f11aa027bfc9874cd58cb"]="/home/rob/Desktop/file.dat"
hashes_and_files["5b73c2a88fab97f558a07d40cc1e9d8e"]="/home/rob/Desktop/test2.exe"

#finding is trivial

find_hash = "5b73c2a88fab97f558a07d40cc1e9d8e"
file_name = hashes_and_files["5b73c2a88fab97f558a07d40cc1e9d8e"]
```